# Need to find the correct PHP string

Tags: php, string

I want one else if to return result for more than one value.
This is returning the information as 0534 holds.
I have some more values that i want to return. But not sure how to do this?
Is not possible to use stristr for this?

```
} else if( stristr( $product->prodno, '0534' ) ) {       
    $enlargements []= $productarray;
}
```

Grateful for any help i can get.

Comment: You could use a `switch` or a `foreach`-loop.
I don't really get what you are tying to do.

Comment: You can add `||` OR operand to check for more conditions. Is that what you looking for? could you show an example with multiple values you want to return. like: are you trying to do `stristr( $product->prodno, '0534' || $product->prodno, '1234'  || $product->prodno, '4236' ){ return multiple}`  something like this ?

Comment: yes correct, im trying to do exatly as you example! but the script is crashing

Comment: the prodnr is holding several values i want to select only some few.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia got it to work finally

Comment: Okay, that's really great. What was it that worked out?